# How can I get the ID by name in a spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I want to get id of particular name that i selected in spinner.i did like this but it will print "_id" how can i retrieve id of particular name.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
    int arg2, long arg3) {          
    String sel_name,numbers;            
    //String[] name=new String[]{arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString()};


    sel_name=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
    String[] p=new String[]{People._ID};
    Cursor cur=getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, p,People.NAME+"= '"+sel_name+"'" ,null , null);
    String r=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People._ID)); 
    Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(),r, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a cursor.moveToFirst();  call before you use the cursor.

Comment: thanks for reply but i didn't get answer.i store all name in spinner.if i select any name from spinner that is store in sel_name so i want _id of that particular name.can you write query for this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to sel_name, then this is what you should do to get the view's id:

```
sel_name = String.valueOf(arg0.getChildAt(arg2).getId());
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i didn't get answer.i store all name in spinner.if i select any name from spinner that is store in sel_name so i want _id of that particular name.can you write query for this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

add following after cursor

```
while(cur.moveToNext)
{
   String r=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People._ID));
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i didn't get answer.i store all name in spinner.if i select any name from spinner that is store in sel_name so i want _id of that particular name.can you write query for this. thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are using the back of 2.0 api. well Try this to find ID of certain Contact.
`Cursor cur=getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, People.Data._ID, People.NAME+"= '"+sel_name+"'", null, null);
 while(cur.moveToNext)
 {
       cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(People.Data._ID))
  }`

Answer (score 0):

by id of perticular name if you mean a string den avoid to do so . alw
ays use id as int only ,because R file have int entries only , so will be easy to handle .

for this i guess in onItemSelected 
 arg1.getId() will work ........

or try setTag(id) in get view of customAdapter of spinner , then in onItemSelected int id = arg1.getTag();

Comment: thanks for reply but i didn't get answer.i store all name in spinner.if i select any name from spinner that is store in sel_name so i want _id of that particular name.can you write query for this. thanks in advance

Comment: sorry......i help till that level to girls only .... jokes apart store names in an array ......now in onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3)  int arg2 is your selected position . like String myname = nameArray[arg2];